# How do you completely remove sqlite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, uninstallation, sqlite3-ruby

I tried doing this

```
gem uninstall sqlite3-ruby
gem uninstall sqlite3
```

Then I performed `find ~/ | grep mkmf.log`

And it removed any sqlite3 directory I had on the system.

But it still is in my bin. Anyone know a more professional way of removing sqlite3?

I say this because I've been dealing with this error for five days now :

```
sqlite3-ruby only supports sqlite3 versions 3.6.16+, please upgrade!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I have completely gutted my server three times now and reinstalled every single application and sqlite3 included on to it again and again. But it still thinks its an old header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use `rvm` and `bundler` to manage your gems and gem dependencies.
I never install any gems system-wide, specially on a Mac where it can get really messy dealing with system-wide gems.

It's easy to get rvm + bundler up and started.

First, install rvm (you must have git).

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
# this will be installed on your $HOME/.rvm directory
```

Setup rvm

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Then, install your ruby via rvm

```
rvm install ree # Ruby Enterprise Edition or,
# rvm install 1.9.2
# rvm install 1.8.7
```

Switch to your ruby compiler

```
rvm use ree
```

Create your gemset to easily switch to different gem versions.

```
rvm gemset create rails3 # where rails3 is the gemset name
```

Use your gemset

```
rvm use ree@rails3
```

Install bundler

```
gem install bundler # without sudo
```

Create a Gemfile and install your gems.

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
bundle init # this will create a Gemfile
echo "gem 'rails'" >> Gemfile
echo "gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
```

About your original post, if it's a system install, you can check it by running `which sqlite3_ruby` and if it returns `/usr/bin/sqlite3_ruby` then you should prepend `sudo` to `gem uninstall` command.

Comment: All things aside I gave you the answer because it was a nice new direction. But after doing all this, I'm still left with the same problem. :D

Comment: well you can always just rename the file, if it's under /usr/lib/sqlite3, then rename the folder, if it's /usr/bin/sqlite3 just rename the file to .old

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby gem is just a wrapper around the "real" SQLite which is a library plus a command line tool. So removing the gem doesn't remove the library/cli. You need to remove that with whatever packaging tool your operating system provides (you didn't tell us which OS you're using), like `yast` or `apt` or `pkg`...

Comment: Its under webfaction's hosting. So it was installed via wget http://www.sqlite.org/..  . Then from there I performed `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`

Comment: Since you've manually installed it, you must manually delete it :-) Delete the `sqlite` command in `$HOME/bin` and the `libsqlite*` files in `$HOME/lib`. Don't know if there's anything else to delete like manpages and stuff...

Comment: Yep thought I had it all deleted. Guess I didn't though.